# Send SPL per lamport for msg.sender solana alternative

Tags: spl, solang, payer

I just switched to solana from solidity.
currently im using solang for ease of use.
I know in solana there is no msg.sender but solana can detect payer of tx.
I want to write a program that will send 1token per lamport to payer of tx.
it means a i need a contract or program address. when a user sent 1 lamport to that he recive 1 spl-token of an already minted token.
it require 4 features

- solana program be able to recive lamport
- solana program be able to detect who payed the lamport transaction
- solana program be able to detect how much lamport recived
- solana program be able to recive and send spl token

is it possible to do this in solana ?

✏️ Edit :
The problem here is not finding msg.sender. i want send spl to person who paid the fee. Problem is detecting amount of lampons and sending slp

Comment: We've wanted to expose the fee payer of a transaction to the runtime for a long time, but it hasn't been done yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's quickly get into why there isn't necessarily a `msg.sender` like you're used to on Ethereum.

On Solana, you cannot guarantee that the person who paid the fee on the transaction is the traditional `msg.sender` you're used to on Ethereum. This is because anyone can pay the fee on a transaction. The only additional work is a required signature from the fee payer.

If you want to do something like `msg.sender` on Solana, you can check if the signer is equal to a specific address you're expecting. For example, you can do the following:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Hf96fZsgq9R6Y1AHfyGbhi9EAmaQw2oks8NqakS6XVt1");

#[program]
pub mod signer_check {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let the_signer1: &mut Signer = &mut ctx.accounts.signer1;

                // Function logic....

        msg!("The signer1: {:?}", *the_signer1.key);

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer1: Signer<'info>,
}
```

With the above code you could potentially check that `the_signer1` is equal to a publicKey you're expecting. With this you should be able to get started with all of your requirements.

If you want to send a certain amount of SPL given an amount of lamports received, simply take in the lamports received and send an amount from a token account that the program controls.

This is rough code, but something like:

```
pub fn transfer_sol_and_tokens(ctx: Context<TransferContext>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        **ctx.accounts.payer.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount;
        **ctx.accounts.recipient.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount;

        transfer(
        CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.sender_token_account.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.recipient_token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: ctx.accounts.sender.to_account_info(),
            },
        ),
        amount * 10u64.pow(ctx.accounts.mint_account.decimals as u32), // Transfer amount, adjust for decimals
    )?;
        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferContext<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    recipient: SystemAccount<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint_account: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        associated_token::mint = mint_account,
        associated_token::authority = sender,
    )]
    pub sender_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = sender,
        associated_token::mint = mint_account,
        associated_token::authority = recipient,
    )]
    pub recipient_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
}
```

You can find the individual examples of [sending SOL in a program](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/basics/transfer-sol/anchor/programs/transfer-sol/src/lib.rs#L28-L35) and [sending tokens](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/transfer-tokens/anchor/programs/transfer-tokens/src/instructions/transfer.rs#L36-L67) within the program examples.

Resources:

- [Program Examples](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples)
- [EVM to SVM Bootcamp(msd.sender)](https://www.rareskills.io/post/msg-sender-solana)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I mentioned this point in my question, sorry if it wasn't clear. I want to send spl token to the payer according to the amount of lamport received.  It means that it doesn't matter who made the transaction, the one who paid the fee is my target. Problem here is measuring amount and sending slp

Comment: Updated with the answer

Comment:  Thank you very much